Query on reinforcement learning model not converging
I was trying to build a reinforcement model to personalise email campaign (basis email variants, time of day etc.) and improve open rates.
For this, I created a DQN model and followed epsilon decay approach . When I run the model on synthetic customers it seems to always converge on the same action. I want to send only one action per customer, but it always converges on the same action irrespective of random sample. Can you please help me debug this.
Snippet -


class EmailMarketingEnv(py_environment.PyEnvironment):

    def __init__(self, treatment_customers):

        self.treatment_customers = treatment_customers

        self.current_customer_idx = 0  # Track the current customer being processed

        self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=num_actions - 1, name='action')

        self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(3,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=6, name='observation')

        self._state = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int32)

        self._episode_ended = False



    def action_spec(self):

        return self._action_spec



    def observation_spec(self):

        return self._observation_spec



    def _reset(self):

        self._state = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int32)

        self._episode_ended = False

        return ts.restart(self._state)



    def _step(self, action):

        if self._episode_ended or self.current_customer_idx >= len(self.treatment_customers):

            return self.reset()



        # Process the current customer

        customer = self.treatment_customers[self.current_customer_idx]

        customer_id, preferred_variant, preferred_time, preferred_day = customer



        # Decode the action into (email_variant, time_of_day, day_of_week)

        email_variant, time_of_day, day_of_week = decode_action(action)



        # Calculate reward for the current customer based on action taken

        reward = 1 if (email_variant == preferred_variant and time_of_day == preferred_time and day_of_week == preferred_day) else 0



        # Record the action and reward

        treatment_records.append([customer_id, email_variant, time_of_day, day_of_week, reward])



        # Mark the episode as ended for this customer and move to the next customer

        self.current_customer_idx += 1

        self._episode_ended = True



        return ts.termination(self._state, reward)



# Step 5: Set up RL DQN Agent

env = EmailMarketingEnv(treatment_customers)

tf_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(env)



# Create Q-Network

fc_layer_params = (100,)

# Example: Add dropout to the Q-Network architecture

q_net = q_network.QNetwork(

    tf_env.observation_spec(),

    tf_env.action_spec(),

    fc_layer_params=(100,),

    dropout_layer_params=(0.1,)  # Adding dropout with 10% dropout rate

)



# Optimizer and train step counter

optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)

train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)



# Create the DQN agent

agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(tf_env.time_step_spec(), tf_env.action_spec(), q_network=q_net, optimizer=optimizer, td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss, train_step_counter=train_step_counter)

agent.initialize()



# Epsilon-greedy action selection for exploration and exploitation

def select_action(agent, time_step, epsilon):

    if random.uniform(0, 1) < epsilon:

        action_index = np.random.choice(num_actions)

    else:

        action_index = agent.policy.action(time_step).action.numpy()[0]

    return decode_action(action_index)



# Epsilon decay over training

initial_epsilon = 1.0

final_epsilon = 0.1

epsilon_decay = 0.995  # Decay factor





# Step 6: Send actions to treatment customers using RL model and track rewards

epsilon = initial_epsilon

for customer_idx in range(len(treatment_customers)):

    time_step = tf_env.reset()  # Reset for each customer

    action = select_action(agent, time_step, epsilon)

# Reduce epsilon over time

    epsilon = max(final_epsilon, epsilon * epsilon_decay)



    # Send the action to the environment and get the reward

    time_step = tf_env.step(encode_action(*action))

    reward = time_step.reward.numpy()[0]



print(f"Treatment Customer {treatment_customers[customer_idx][0]}: Action -> {action}, Reward -> {reward}")



I expect for the model to converge into different actions as rewards are different for random samples.
